# Send a list of parameters in angular and change route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I trying to call other route in angular, similar this

$location.path($scope.productPath+"/approveProducts/").search({ids});

I want send the list of ids to other controller but the ids are sending by url

http://localhost:8080/#/product?ids=1130&ids=1132&ids=7428&ids=15574&ids=15579&ids=15580&ids=6798968768697789

I need send ids similar a post requisition, not in a url, because i have a many ids in my call

How i do this in angular, send parameters and change my route to other controller?

Answer (score 1):

I believe a better approach might be to utilize the angularjs service/factory to persist your data.

example:

```
.service('AngularJsService', function() {
    var listOfIds = [];
    return {
       saveData: function(theIdsToSave) {
          listOfIds = theIdsToSave;
       },
       getData: function () {
          return listOfIds;
       }
    }
}
.controller('OriginatingController', function($location, AngularJsService) {
    function navigateToTargetController() {
       AngularJsService.saveData([1,2,3,4]);
       $location.path('pathToTargetController');
    }
}
.controller('TargetController', function($location, AngularJsService) {
    function retrieveData() {
       var ids = AngularJsService.getData();
       // ids = [1,2,3,4]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$http` for send your params and then change your route

```
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://example.com',// address for sending ids
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': undefined
 },
 data: { test: 'test' }
}

$http(req).then(function(){
    // this you can to change your url
    $location.path($scope.productPath+"/approveProducts/");
}, function(){...});
```

Comment: thanks but I need change the route, send parameters to other controller